# Non-stop While Loop run without getting expected results

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have been given an assignment which requires me to use interval bisection to calculate the square root of a value, within 10e-12. I have my code here, and it doesn't return any errors when compiling, but it has been running for about 5 minutes and hasn't returned a result. What have I done wrong here? Here's my code.

```cpp
#include "fcpp.hh"

double biit(double min, double max, double x)
{
    double mid = (max + min) / 2;

    while(fabs((mid * mid) - x) > 10E-12)
    {
        if(mid * mid > x)
        {
            min = min;
            max = mid;
            mid = (min + max) / 2;
        }

        else if(min * min < x)
        {
            min = mid;
            max = max;
            mid = (min + max) / 2;
        }
    }

    return mid;
}

int main()
{
    print(biit(enter_doub("interval min:"), enter_doub("interval max:"), enter_doub("take square root of:")));  

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are switching on `min*min` being on either side of `x` rather than `mid*mid`. Consider what happens when you try to find the square root of `4` bounded by `1` and `10`:

```
biit(1, 10, 4);
```

On the first call, the tuple `(min, mid, max)` is: `(1, 5.5, 10)`. Since 5.5 is a bad guess, you iterate onward... but instead of iterating lower, you iterate *higher*... you use your second if branch, so your tuple becomes `(5.5, 7.75, 10)`. At this point, you have no hope of success since your `min` is already larger than your answer.

Change to:

```
if (mid * mid > x) {
    max = mid;
}
else {
    min = mid;
}

mid = (min + max) / 2;
```

By the way, if you tried to debug this at all, printing out what `min`, `mid`, and `max` become at each iteration, the problem would've been very clear.

Comment: That fixed it :) I didn't see that I'd put two min values instead of mid values. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

did you want `while(fabs((mid * mid) - x) > 10E-12)`? misbalanced parentheses? You will always get something for that....

Also, did you want to do `if(...){}else if(...){}`? You have got `>` and `<` conditions in your `if` flow, but what happens when it is `==`. In C/C++ 3 is NOT >3 and also 3 is NOT <3. 3 is ONLY EVER == 3 Has it ever come across to you :) ?

How about doing `if(>=){} else if(<)` ? Also, debugger is your good friend - don't forget that :)

Comment: I didn't catch that, thanks. It's still not returning a result for me, though.

Comment: @NigelTh0rnberry     Also, did you mean `if(..){}else if(...){}` because at some point you will end up going in both `if`s.....Check my updated answer. Also, a `.hh` file? I might be a bit outdated for C++ file extensions in this case :(